# How to create javascript function constructor with default functionality and persistent properties?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've got a slightly unusual pattern I'm trying to achieve and have not quite figured it out. My goal is to create a function called debugLog as a flexible console.log replacement, which can be called as follows:

```
debugLog('thing to log #1', 'thing to log #2', objectToLog1, objectToLog2);
```

^^ the number of params should be arbitrary, just as is possible with console.log

That is what I'll call the "default" functionality. Now I'd also like to add some additional functionality through property functions.

Examples:

```
debugLog.setDebugFlag(true); // sets the internal this.debugFlag property to true or false depending on param
```

I'm trying to do this in Node and what I have so far does not quite let me achieve this pattern:

```
var debugLog = function () {
  this.debugFlag = this.debugFlag || true;
  if (this.debugFlag) {
    console.log.apply(null, arguments);
  } else {
    // production mode, nothing to log
  }
};

debugLog.prototype.setDebugFlag = function (flagBool) {
  this.debugFlag = flagBool;
}

module.exports = new debugLog();
```

This module would be including in a Node app using the standard require pattern:

```
var debugLog = require('./debugLog.js');
```

The question is how can I achieve this pattern of a function object with default functionality, but also extended "property" style functions? Please note I am already aware of the typical pattern where ALL functionality comes from function properties (such as debugLog.log() and debugLog.setDebugFlag()). But that patterns does NOT achieve my key goal of a shorthand for the default functionality that simply involves calling the function directly.

Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way

```
var debugLog = (function() {
  var debugFlag = true;

  function log() {
    if (debugFlag) {
      console.log.apply(null, arguments);
    } else {
      // production mode, nothing to log
    }
  };

  log.setDebugFlag = function(flag) {
    debugFlag = flag;
  }
  return log;
})();

module.exports = debugLog;
```

Comment: OP is talking about a NodeJS module.. this would be good for clientside

Answer (score 1):

You could use closure, like so:

```
// debugLog.js
var debugFlag = true;

function debugLog() {
    if (debugFlag) {
        console.log.apply(null, arguments);
    } else {
        // production mode, nothing to log
    }
}

debugLog.setDebugFlag = function (newFlag) {
    debugFlag = newFlag;
}

module.exports = debugLog;
```

and use it like this:

```
// otherFile.js

var debugLog = require('./debugLog');
debugLog('Hey!');
debugLog.setDebugFlag(false);
debugLog('This wont appear!');
```

Comment: If there are more functions in that module your lack of encapsulation could cause problems.

Comment: @SpiderPig It's perfectly encapsulated for use as a module in NodeJS.. much better than wrapping it in an unnecessary IIFE, which would ALSO capture the scope of any "more functions in that module".

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I understand your comment about it being encapsulated as a module in Node, because that file would have its own scope automatically, preventing leakage. But what do you mean that an IIFE would also capture the scope of any "more functions in that module"?

Comment: @JoJo have a google for "javascript closure" - the purpose of the IIFE is to create a new scope for the variables being used.  This "new" scope closes around the surrounding scope, meaning the only difference is that `debugFlag` would be available to other functions in the module in my example, but not in the IIFE example (unless those functions were also declared inside the IIFE).  This has both pros and cons, and can be rectified easily in both situations.. but it's not often you see an entire NodeJS module wrapped in an IIFE - because its pointless.